# Install windows on external harddrive and use it with my mac?

Tags: windows, macbook-pro, parallels

I know there is lot's of guides out there on the net, but I havn't really found a good one  which explains step by step how it works :/ For that reason I hope some of you guys could give me some pointers...

I'm currently using a MacBook Pro for developing webpages, but I need Internet Explorer in order to optimize for all browsers. Therefore I tried installing Windows on my MacBook using BootCamp, but unfortunately I don't have space enough on my harddrive to do so. As a result of that I'm looking for an alternative...

I've read that it should be possible to install Windows on an external harddrive using Parallels - is that true? If yes, do you have a step-by-step guide on how to do so? And is it important which kind of external harddrive it is?

If it's possible, I would also like to know how it works after installing. Can you just plugin your external harddrive and switch to windows desktop using shortcuts or how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is installing vmware or VirtualBox on your mac and creating a new machine and putting its files on the external drive.

Comment: How much space do it take to install vmware or VirtualBox on my mac? And is it easy to switch between external/windows and mac or do I have to reboot everytime?

Comment: less than 100MB, it's not difficult and does not need to reboot everytime.

Comment: But how much space does Windows installation then take? I guess this were the problem in BootCamp..

Comment: it depends, XP needs about 5GB, win7 needs 15GB

Comment: I installed WIN7 on my macbook pro now.. But I can't access either "http://localhost" or "http://localhost:8888/", so how do I find the localhost from the VirtualBox Machine?

Comment: Figured it out in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine ... Thanks for the help :)